# PHP Display Button if Certain Value is So and So

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently programming a PHP application, and I am wondering if it is possible for a link to only show if a certain database variable is so and so.

For example, have PHP check if the value for the user currently logged in is "Admin" under the "Rank" variable in the table, and if it is, display the link. If not, don't show anything.

Many thanks, and if anyone is confused, I'm willing to give more details.

Comment: Please add what you currently tried and tested. Add your sql tables as well as php code

Comment: Haven't been able to think this through; probably because it's midnight, so I don't know how to do this. I'm relatively new to the PHP language, coming from computer programming.

Comment: Yes, you can do the process, it is possible to give conditions based on the database fields,
Firstly you have to fire a query and fetch the record for the Admin or any other user, and other records, that you want, then for that record give the php condition <? if(yourdatabasefield == 'your value to be compare') { ?> your link <? } ?>

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this tomorrow after a good night's sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good thing about PHP is that you can merge HTML & PHP code both and here is your answer:

```
    <?php if('databaseField' === 'value to compare'){ ?>
         HTML LINK TAG
    <?php } ?>
```

use === instead of == because you want to match your session value with database value and in case of login too. so for security purpose use ===. it will check type of both variable as well as value.

Feel free to ask for any doubt here.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be working; do I have to first connect to the database and then doing this, because I'm technically already connecting to the database.  (edit): Do I also have to have the Database Field be a specific type, like VARCHARS or something like that?

Comment: <?php
$conn = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db($conn);

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE .....") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php if($data['fieldname'] === 'value to compare'){ ?>
         HTML LINK TAG
<?php } ?>

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. I will try this when I get on my computer; it's dead right now for now reason... -_- Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Your code gave me a great start; did a little improvising and works like a gem! Many thanks, I should go pick up another fat PHP book now; skills getting REALLY rusty...

Comment: Your most welcome. Let me know for any kind of help i can do. It will be pleasure to me... :)